Пропадает курсор и не работают кнопки в Unity
У меня не работают кнопки и пропадает курсор, и когда скачал на телефон, он тоже не работает, а когда я поменял с Game на Simulator, он у меня полностью работает. Помогите пожалуйста.

[

Вы можете в скрипте в методе Start() указать Cursor.visible = true;.
Убедитесь , что на кнопках стоит галка Racast Target. Проверьте, что на кнопках в Unity Event указаны методы, которые они должны вызвать при нажатии.
Так же,зачем вам курсор на смартфоне?

Хз, я думал, что если будет работать курсор, то и на телефоне будут работать кнопки. Я всё проверил, и всё ок, на симуляторе зашел, и всё работает, а как скачал на телефон, кнопки не реагируют.
